# Vue Nuxt.js - deploy in subfolder

Tags: vue.js, assets, nuxt.js, subdirectory

I have a Nuxt.js project and I generate a static app. I need to put it in a  subdirectory on ftp, but I can't make it work.

I've set `router.base` to `/subfolder` and that works fine for `_nuxt`, but static files are still using absolute path `/img/...`

So I've tried to put my static files into `assets/img/`, but they are not getting loaded from scss when I use `~assets/img/...`

I've read many topics, but couldn't find the solution.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding solutions in the documentation as well, but I found out you can use the static folder on a subdomain if the links are changed from:

`/image.jpg`

to:

`~/static/image.jpg`

Also if it helps, I believe changing:

`~assets/image.jpg`

to

`~/assets/image.jpg`

Might solve your issue?

Comment: I also tried to set router base to "." and that works well for templates, but css gets the path wrong. Like /.nuxt/.nuxt/... 
In css you can only use ~assets, nothing else works.
I read quite a few posts about it, but found no solution.

Thank you anyways

Comment: Yeah coming back to this question, I ran into the same issue.  Never found an alternative answer either :(